# Windows 8.1 high cpu load from system idle process

Tags: high-cpu-usage

I am running W8.1 on a elder Dell Latitude D830. Now the CPU load is permanent at a minimum of 50%, mostly for the system idle process

On my process explorer I can see 55% System Idle process, and on properties I found two threats ntoskrnl.exe!KiDispatchinterrupt+0x588

This is from start, no matter a programm is running. My laptop is overheatend, all fans permanently running. Soon it will die.

I checked Mr. Google for any entries but without sucess. Any help welcome, thank you in advance

Comment: What makes you think those processes are malicious threats?

Comment: Your laptip shouldn't 'die' from ovetheating. There's a misconception that laptops explode when ovetheating when actually the bios shuts down the system way before that would have the possibly to happen. (Even then it wouldn't explode, rather fry your system's components). If you're worried about temps checkout speed fan or core temp to monitor temperature.

Comment: when was the last time it was opened up & thoroughly cleaned?

Answer (score 3):

System idle process is whatever is leftover. it is what is NOT being used. a 99% for system idle process would mean that you CPU was only using 1% of its ability.